# How can I send email and SMS together using Laravel 5.5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sms-gateway, laravel-notification

How can I send email and SMS together using Laravel 5.5 ?

Should I use mailable and SMS service or Notification with SMS and How ?

Comment: You can create a common function and send both, email you can send using laravel function and for SMS you have to use gateway like twilio ..etc.

Comment: follow this link https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications

Comment: Read the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/notifications

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event in laravel's App/Events folder.
put all the code for send mail and sms with there configuration, just call that event wherever you want to hit sms or mail.

Answer (score 0):

You may create one function which will include both notify() method for an email and dispatch() method for message
example

```
   public function Notification(Model $tender)
{
    $user = access()->user();
    /* Send confirmation email */
        $tender->notify(new Email($user));

    /* Send confirmation message */

    Send::dispatch($user);
}
```

Then you will just call a single function that is Notification() which will do both sending email and message